# docker containers: mariaDB connection issue with nextcloud

Tags: docker, mariadb, nextcloud

I'm the super user at my maschine. There is docker inside my volumne (`/volume1/docker`). I pulled the latest version of the images and run MariaDB, PhpMyAdmin and NextCloud:

```
docker run -d --name mariadb --network nextcloud --network-alias db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=r00tp@ss -e MYSQL_USER=nextcloud_rw -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=N3xtCl0ud! -e MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud -v /volume1/docker/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql --restart=unless-stopped mariadb:latest

docker run -d --name phpmyadmin --network nextcloud --link mariadb:db -e PMA_ARBITRARY=1 -e PMA_HOST=db -e PMA_USER=nextcloud_rw -e PMA_PASSWORD=N3xtCl0ud! -p 8082:80 --restart=unless-stopped phpmyadmin:latest

docker run -d --name nextcloud --network nextcloud -e MYSQL_HOST=db -e MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud -e MYSQL_USER=nextcloud_rw -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=N3xtCl0ud! -v /volume1/docker/nextcloud:/var/www/html -v db:/var/lib/mysql --restart=unless-stopped -p 8080:80 nextcloud:latest
```

When I open the browser and navigate to `http:\\whereNextCloudLives:8080`, I see the NextClud background plus the installation form. I enter the user `nextcloud` and the pw `N3xtCl0ud!` and get the response "Please check your mysql credentials. Cannot connect to DB".

MariaDB-Log:

```
[Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
[Note] [Entrypoint]: Securing system users (equivalent to running mysql_secure_installation)
[Note] [Entrypoint]: Giving user nextcloud_rw access to schema nextcloud
[Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user nextcloud_rw
[Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database nextcloud
[Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
stderr  Version: '10.9.3-MariaDB-1:10.9.3+maria~ubu2204'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  mariadb.org binary distribution
[Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
[Warning] Access denied for user 'nextcloud_rw'@'172.18.0.4' (using password: YES)
[Warning] Access denied for user 'nextcloud_rw'@'172.18.0.4' (using password: YES)
[Warning] Access denied for user 'nextcloud_rw'@'172.18.0.4' (using password: YES)
stderr  Version: '10.9.3-MariaDB-1:10.9.3+maria~ubu2204'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

NextCloud-Log:

```
442381598Z  stdout  172.18.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2022:18:26:11 +0000] "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3538 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2022-12-02T18:26:11.300610626Z  stdout  127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2022:18:26:11 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.54 (Debian) PHP/8.0.24 (internal dummy connection)"
2022-12-02T18:26:05.648774341Z  stdout  172.18.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2022:18:26:04 +0000] "GET /dist/core-common.js.map?v=dc4002698c876c22453e HTTP/1.1" 200 4483569 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2022-12-02T18:26:04.864831573Z  stdout  172.18.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2022:18:26:04 +0000] "GET /dist/core-main.js.map?v=0a05117109bf8b6240ea HTTP/1.1" 200 106976 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2022-12-02T18:26:04.845899731Z  stdout  172.18.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2022:18:26:04 +0000] "GET /core/vendor/zxcvbn/dist/zxcvbn.js.map HTTP/1.1" 404 680 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2022-12-02T18:26:04.844799000Z  stdout  172.18.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2022:18:26:04 +0000] "GET /dist/core-install.js.map?v=ee580b4e58a4177adf85 HTTP/1.1" 200 9627 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2022-12-02T18:26:04.331553336Z  stdout  172.18.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2022:18:26:04 +0000] "GET /core/img/manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 200 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2022-12-02T18:25:47.268364543Z  stderr  [Fri Dec 02 18:25:47.267810 2022] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
2022-12-02T18:25:47.268255142Z  stderr  [Fri Dec 02 18:25:47.267778 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.54 (Debian) PHP/8.0.24 configured -- resuming normal operations
2022-12-02T18:25:47.252431732Z  stderr  AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
2022-12-02T18:25:47.240345812Z  stderr  AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

I just use the IP. There is no domain configured. I've access to the DB with PhpMyAdmin.
Anyone with an idea what is wrong?

Comment: Can you delete the volume for db and try again? The idea being to recreate db container from scratch.

Comment: WOW. Something was wrong inside the volumes. I removed all volumnes - restart the container and perfect result. Thank you  @Tony

Comment: Once the volumes are initialized, changing the environment variable has no effect.